# What is the real use of Base.OnInspectorGUI?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Sphere))]
public class SphereEditor : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Sphere sphere = (Sphere)target;//casting from type object to type sphere

        GUILayout.Label("Oscillates around a base size.");

        sphere.baseSize = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Size", sphere.baseSize, .1f, 2f);

        sphere.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * sphere.baseSize;
    }

}
```

What is the use of `Base.OnInspectorGUI`.According to the internet, it is said that the use of it is to utilize the original functino of GUI setted by unity.However , without it , everything work fine . Any one who can tell the ans with full explaination is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to use `base.OnInspectorGUI` or any other method which you are overriding and yes everything should just go fine as your code. But however, whenever we override a method you are basically saying that I don't want the default functionality of `xyz()` method I want to create my own function instead so you override a method from the base class. but if you want to something on top of the existing functionality, then it would be a lengthy process instead of what if somehow we can add your own code in already system defined methods which is exactly you can do with `base.OnInspectorGUI`. Not just **OnInspectorGUI** you can do this for any method as long as they are over-ridable.

Happy coding

Comment: So using `base.OnInspectorGUI` can help retain the original functionality  , but what is the meaning of doing these?

Comment: check these two images [with base.OnInspectorGUI()](https://prnt.sc/r60l4o) and [without the base metohd](https://prnt.sc/r60lge).

Comment: I guess I understand what's your mean.keeping base.xxx can help retain the functionality and then when i add  the custom inspector and press in somebuttons , there can then show the effect of what im doing csince i ave used this command

Comment: This is what it means. Just remember that ```base.xxxxx()``` will call the same function which you are overriding and you can whatever you want after ```base.xxx()``` to add more functionality to that function.